# Amazon S3 putObject() - not working - PHP

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm using the standalone PHP-S3 class:
http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class

I've tried all the ready made tutorials, downloaded the source, changed the corresponding variables (set my bucket, access_key, access_secret).

I'm guetting the following error whenever I try to upload any file:
`Warning: S3::putObject(): [417] Unexpected HTTP status in C:\Users\Jad\Dropbox\www\test\S3.php on line 312`

**Note:** My bucket already exists and I even allowed all the permissions to the user `everyone` (temporarily for it to work but it's still not working)

Comment: what us the HTTP status that you get there?

Comment: @ElzoValugi it is between brackets: 417

Comment: 417 Expectation failed. Just like my expectations that people will google an error before posting here

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=296676

Comment: http://www.cloudberrylab.com/forum/?g=posts&m=10506

Comment: @ElzoValugi No, still not working and the first link is totally irrelevant

Comment: **The same code is working online (just tested it)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I created a new bucket in the US (the last one was in Ireland) and everything works smoothly now.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.
If you are connected through a proxy in my case it worked connection to S3 over SSL.

```
$s3 = new S3(S3KEY, S3SECRET,  true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I'm connected to a proxy... If I'm connected to an other network, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue behind a squid3 proxy and the problem was resolved by the following squid configuration directive:

```
ignore_expect_100 on
```